# How to create non blocking popup

Tags: android, android-widget

How to create non blocking Popup

```
                         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                         PollRatings.this
                         .getContext().getSystemService(
                         Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                         View layout = inflater
                         .inflate(R.layout.toast, null);
                         PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300,
                         470,
                         true);
                         pw.setFocusable(true);
                         pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                         pw.setTouchable(true);
                         pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

but when I shows popup, other widgets on screen are blicked ( I cannot click on anything ) HOw to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `Toast`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

Comment: I cannot use Toast because I need to reset time, tried with cancel and make new with new message but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Then try to cancel the dialog from the code by starting a timer and doing dialog.cancel() in the run() procedure of the timer.